# Using An Array on Multiple Web Forms and within a DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, dll, fortran

I have an input web form that will take in 45 user entered data, and then once the user has entered all data he/she can click a button that takes the 45 inputs, does a calculation via a DLL file, and then places all the output information on a different web form page. My question is how do I collect all the 45 input data, and place them into an array which both the DLL can access and the output form? I believe the back end of the dll is written in fortran and the original developer passed the visual basic array into the dll by using "ByRef ArrayInput As Double".

Answer (score 0):

Since the original was Fortran you need to use standard calling convention.  Try code like below :

```
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("MyDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern uint CallWithDouble(IntPtr data);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[,] myDoubleArray = new double[9, 5];
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(myDoubleArray));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(myDoubleArray, ptr, true);

            uint results = CallWithDouble(ptr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Ian Bush : I spelled Fortran correctly but the spell checker at this site changed it.

Comment: That's probably your web browser's spellchecker.